# Efficient algorithm for removing an array from another array

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm wondering if anyone knows a better (as in faster) algorithm/solution to solve my problem:

In my program I have an array of uints, from which I want to remove the entries contained in another uint array. However, I cannot use the union of the sets, because I need to keep duplicate values. Badly worded explaination, but the example should make it a bit clearer:

```
    uint[] array_1 = new uint[7] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4};
    uint[] array_2 = new uint[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    uint[] result = array_1 .RemoveRange(array_2);
    // result should be: { 1, 1, 4 }
```

This is my current best idea; but it's fairly slow:

```
    public static uint[] RemoveRange(this uint[] source_array, uint[] entries_to_remove)
    {
        int current_source_length = source_array.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < entries_to_remove.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < current_source_length; j++)
            {
                if (entries_to_remove[i] == source_array[j])
                {
                    // Shifts the entries in the source_array.
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(source_array, (j + 1)* 4 , source_array, j * 4, (current_source_length - j) * 4);
                    current_source_length--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        uint[] new_array = new uint[current_source_length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(source_array, 0, new_array, 0, current_source_length * 4);
        return new_array;
    }
```

So again, can someone come up with a more clever approach to achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: You should not resize arrays yourself.  Instead, use `List<T>`.

Comment: It's not really a set since there are duplicates...

Comment: How are you using the result? Does it have to be an array or is any `IEnumerable<uint>` okay? And does order matter?

Comment: are duplicates possible in `array_2` ?

Comment: Order doesn't matter, and yeah, it has to be an array. Also, I know it's not technically a set, but I felt the question was more "understandable" with that wording :p

Comment: "Set" typically implies no duplicate elements, from the mathematical definition of a set. To avoid confusion, don't use the word "set" if you want to allow duplicates.

Comment: @BrokenGlass duplicates are possible in both arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do what you want as far as I understand it, they key is reference counting of the number of occurrences and then using the remaining reference count (if > 0) as the number of times a number has to be emitted:

```
public static uint[] RemoveRange(this uint[] source_array, uint[] entries_to_remove)
{
    var referenceCount = new Dictionary<uint, int>();
    foreach (uint n in source_array)
    {
        if (!referenceCount.ContainsKey(n))
            referenceCount[n] = 1;
        else
            referenceCount[n]++;
    }
    foreach (uint n in entries_to_remove)
    {
        if (referenceCount.ContainsKey(n))
            referenceCount[n]--;
    }
    return referenceCount.Where(x => x.Value > 0)
                         .Select(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x.Key, x.Value))
                         .SelectMany( x => x)
                         .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using a `Dictionary<uint,int>` using the uint number as the key and the number of times the number occurs as the value?

```
var source = new Dictionary<uint,int>();
source.Add(1,3);
source.Add(2,1);
source.Add(3,1);
source.Add(4,2);

var remove = new uint[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
for (int i = 0; i<remove.Length; i++) {
    int occurences;
    if (source.TryGet(remove[i], out occurences)) {    
        if (occurences>1) {
            source[remove[i]] = occurences-1;
        } else {
            source.Remove(remove[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This won't help you, since you want to keep duplicates.
I'm leaving it here for people who don't want duplicates.

Create a `HashSet<T>` from the second list, then call `List<T>.RemoveAll` with the hashset's `Contains` method.

```
var unwanted = new HashSet<uint(...);
list.RemoveAll(unwanted.Contains);
```

If you don't want to remove them in-place, you can use LINQ:

```
list.Except(unwanted);
```

`Except` will build two hashsets and return items one at a time (deferred execution0

Comment: Except `HashSet` doesn't allow duplicates, which is exactly what OP wants.

Comment: {1,1,1,2,3}.RemoveRange({1,2,3}) will for example return an empty set, while it should return {1, 1}.

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays aren't sorted, sort them. Initialize 3 indexes to 0.  's'(source) and 'd' (dest) index the big array A,  'r' indexes the "toRemove" array B.

```
   While r<B.length,
           While B[r] > A[s], A[d++]= A[s++].   
            If B[r]==A[s], s++.
             r++.
    Endwhile. 
    While s<A.length,  A[d++]= A[s++].
     A.length = d.
```

This takes no extra space, and runs in O(N), (or N lg N if they are initially unsorted), compared to the N^2 I your original solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using Linq here,

```
var resultarray = array1.Except(array2);
```

Comment: This doesn't keep duplicates either. And the variable name is misleading, `resultarray` is not an array.